# Ruby on Rails: render action return value when format is json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got 31 method ending with `render :json => blah_blah_blah`, thats annoying.

My idea is to set default response type and render actions return value.
First part is done:

```
before_filter do
  request.format = :json unless params[:format]
end
```

but I can't make up anything with second part of this idea. I've tried around_filter,
but it doesn't get return value, tried to play with default_render, but it can't get actions return value :(

Any ideas how to do something like that?

Regards, Daniel.

Comment: a hacky way: http://pastebin.com/gHEmK2p2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [class level respond_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/ClassMethods/respond_to)

And something like this in your controller should do the trick:

```
def process_action(method_name, *args)
  self.response_body = send_action(method_name, *args).to_json
end
```

or maybe:

```
def process_action(method_name, *args)
  self.response_body = call(method_name, *args).to_json
end
```

Comment: that helps against before_filter, thank you. still i need some better solution for return value.

Comment: Ok, if you want to use the return value of the method for rendering, you'll need to override method process_action (see abstract_controller/base.rb:149), so it'll assign the return value to self.response_body (currently it calls action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4), I mean, something like this in your controller should do the trick: def process_action(method_name, *args); self.response_body = send_action(method_name, *args).to_json; end

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `respond_to`/`respond_with` combo: http://railscasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3.

Comment: i still need to add respond_with(...) everywhere, i'm trying to avoid this code duplication